# Problema al añadir una variable a una lista, relacionada a una función

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, variables

tengo el siguiente problema:

Definí algunas funciones de prueba:

```
import random

r = random

def cosa():
    print ("0")

def cosa1():
    print ("1")

def cosa2():
    print ("2")

def cosa3():
    print ("3")

def cosa4():
    print ("4")
    
def cosa5():
    print ("5")
```

Y luego creé, una lista que contenía los nombres de dichas funciones y una lista vacía:

```
a = [cosa,cosa1,cosa2,cosa3,cosa4,cosa5]
b = []
```

Hasta ahí todo perfecto, el problema, viene que yo, al definir una función, para escoger un elemento random de esta lista `a = [cosa,cosa1,cosa2,cosa3,cosa4,cosa5]`:

```
def sig():
    cosa_actual = r.choice(a)
```

Y luego, al intentar extender la lista `b = []`, utilizando el contenido de la variable `cosa_actual` mediante el uso de:

```
b.extend(cosa_actual)
```

En consola, me arroja que `cosa_actual` es una función, lo cual es verdad, y que por tanto no es iterable, la pregunta es, ¿como podría hacer para guardar en la lista `b = []`, el valor que en su momento me arrojó `cosa_actual = r.choice(a)` y de esa manera yo tener esta lista `b = []` a modo de control de cuales fueron los random previos?

Si no se entiende, lo reformulo, desde ya, muchísimas gracias por leer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL método `list.extend` agrega el contenido de una **secuencia** a la lista, es decir, el objeto tiene que ser iterable de forma que se pueda recorrer y obtener referencias a sus items  para agregarlas a la lista.

> ```
> >>> lista = []
> >>> lista.extend([2, 3])
> >>> lista
> [2, 3]
> >>> lista.extend(range(4, 8))
> >>> lista
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> >>> lista.extend((n for n in range(10) if n % 3))
> >>> lista
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
> >>> lista.extend({13, 17})
> >>> lista
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 17, 13]
> >>> lista.extend("Hola")
> >>> lista
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 17, 13, 'H', 'o', 'l', 'a']
> ```

y así con cualquier objeto iterable.

Si quieres agregar un solo item al final de tu lista, necesitas usar `list.append`:

```
b.append(cosa_actual)
```

Cierto es que podrías envolver la variable en un iterable, por ejemplo:

```
b.extend((cosa_actual, )) # Una tupla
b.extend([cosa_actual])   # Una lista
```

pero no tiene sentido, creas un objeto `list` o `tuple` solo para usar `extend`, lo que además es ineficiente.

Si quisieras insertar el item en otra posición que no sea el final, puedes usar `list.insert(indice, item)`:

> ```
> >>> lista = [2, 3]
> >>> lista.insert(0, 7)
> >>> lista
> [7, 2, 3]
> >>> lista.insert(2, 13)
> >>> lista
> [7, 2, 13, 3]
> ```

Comment: La idea es que en la lista b se guarden los items obtenidos del random.
Por ejemplo, si en la lista b, tengo 10 items, y yo, al setear la variable `cosa_actual` como el valor numero 3 por ejemplo de esa lista y luego al llamar a `cosa_actual`, me traiga esa función asignada a ese item en la segunda lista, la lista b.

¿Se entiende?

Desde ya, muchas gracias, me ayudaste un montón.

Comment: Si, y eso consigues con `cosa_actual = r.choice(a); b.append(cosa_actual)` o directamente `b.append( r.choice(a))`, luego puedes hacer `b[indice]()` y llamas a la función

Comment: `b.append( r.choice(a))` me fué de utilidad, el problema es que cuando quiero mostrar en consola, el penultimo valor de b utilizando: 
`atras = -1
def volver():
    uno_menos = len(b) - atras
    b[uno_menos]()`
No me lo permite porque `uno_menos` no es un item dentro de la listas b y por lo tanto no se puede utilizar con `b[indice]()`

Comment: El penúltimo item de la lista puede ser accedido mediante indizado negativo: `b[-2]()`

Comment: Si, eso lo se, el problema viene cuando quiero mostrar X valor de B asociado a una variable, ej: `C = -1` ahora, `D = len(B)-C` hasta ahora, d tiene un valor X y cuando yo hago `B[C]()` me tira error, el cual está bien, porque me indica que C no es un item en la lista B

¿Cual sería la solución a eso?